# How to refer Environment variables mentioned in openshift deployment, inside python code running in the pod of same deployment

Tags: python, image, containers, openshift, kubernetes-secrets

I am new to Openshift container platform. I am trying to deploy my ML model written in python, which serves the Json request based on authentication of name/password already mentioned in the py code.

```
    @app.before_request
def validate_request():
    try :
        if(request.authorization.username != auth_user or request.authorization.password != auth_password):
            return "Authentication failed: invalid or missing user/password."
    except:
        return "Authentication failed: invalid or missing user/password"
```

Now what I am doing is, I am creating a secrert `dm` in Openshift name-space and adding it in the deployment as below 
[image]

How can I use the username and password mentioned in this secret in my python code, I have tried with [the openshift doc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/secrets.html#secrets-examples)but it doesnt complete my requirement of using the value in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenShift V3 set variable for project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080174/openshift-v3-set-variable-for-project)

Comment: Oh Yes Philip, That was simply done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auth_user = os.environ.get('principle')
auth_password = os.environ.get('credential')
```